# How to release Alicloud by a scheduled date automatically

Tags: terraform

I would like to use Terraform to organize Alicloud ECS which support to automatically release resources for post-paid clients.
Question is how to make use of this feature in Terraform to set a automatic scheduled date to release Alicloud ECS?
I didn't find a clue on tutorial of Website.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/instance.html#auto_release_time

Probably, 8 months ago this feature was not available.

There is an additional solution. `alicloud_instance` resource support `provisioning` block and `aliyun CLI`. You can try something like this:

```
resource "alicloud_instance" "test" {
  image_id = ""
  instance_type = ""
  security_groups = []

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aliyun ModifyInstanceAutoReleaseTime --InstanceId ${self.id} --AutoReleaseTime $release_date"
    environment {
      release_date = timeadd(timestamp(), "5h")
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to add any authorization method to the command in the provisioner.
https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "alicloud_instance" "test" {
auto_release_time=timestamp()+3
 ...
}
```